# How to drop a point in java Swing GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

but I have a homework task to create a Bomberman game,I think i'm doing  fine so far.Me and my team are using "SWING GUI"I have a bomberman walking around the map,but i don't know how to make my bomberman leave a bomb.I want something like when the user press "SPACE" the bomberman to drops a bomb behind.Also if you have any ideas how to make that BOMB explode later i'll be very thankful.

Here is my code so far.As I said I have the bombarian,but don't know how to make him drop new points.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Bombarian extends JFrame {

    int x, y;
    private Image dbImage;
    private Graphics dbg;
    private Point bomb;
    public class AL extends KeyAdapter{

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){

            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
            if (keyCode == e.VK_UP) {
                y--;
            }
            if (keyCode == e.VK_DOWN) {
                y++;            
                        }
            if (keyCode == e.VK_LEFT) {
                x--;
            }
            if (keyCode == e.VK_RIGHT) {
                x++;
            }
            if (keyCode == e.VK_SPACE) {
                bomb = new Point(x,y);
            }

        }
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){

        }
    }

    public Bombarian() {
        addKeyListener(new AL());
        add(new Board());
        setTitle("Bombarian");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(700, 350);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        x = 20;
        y = 45;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        paintComponent(dbg);
        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.fillOval(x, y, 20, 20);
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Bombarian();
    }
}
```

Comment: Best for you to first give it a go at solving your problem. Then if you run into problems with your code, come back with the code.

Comment: 1) Get that `repaint()` call out of paintComponent. Never do that. 2) Call the super method in your `paintComponent` override. 3) Do not override the `paint` method, but instead use your `paintComponent`. 4) Do your drawing in a class that extends JPanel not a top-level window. 5) Read the Graphics tutorials -- don't make this chit up. 6) Give all your attempted override methods `@Override` annotations.

Comment: Use a swing Timer to play the animation, at every tick proceed in time: change x, y and so on; call repaint there.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud simply create a new Object Bomb, which will spawn at the current place of your character and stay there. So the (x,y) coordinates of the Bomb stay the same. If your Background is moving, the Bomb should stick to that Background, so that it seems to stay in the same place. To be able to help you more, you should post your Code or explain how you have programmed your game. Hope I could help.